# Kali linux installation in Virtual box

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, kali-linux

I install virtual box in windows 10. I add  linux and try to deploy, but through  error message as follows

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali.

The virtual machine 'Kali' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Heart Hacker\VirtualBox VMs\Kali\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: Machine Interface:
> IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}

Comment: Did you set up Hardware Virtualization and VT-x in BIOS? Your Kali download was almost for sure 64-bit. I have a Kali Guest in VMware Workstation and it works great.

Comment: Thanm you @John, Virtualisation option not found in the BIOS setting

Comment: I revised my answer. Download Kali 32-bit and use that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your BIOS settings. You need to go into your bios (try del and the function keys on boot) and enable the virtualisation settings in the BIOS. This will under names like VT-d VT-x and virtualisation. Make sure all of those are on. Save those settings and reboot. You should now be able to start the guest.

If Hardware Virtualization is not available, then you can only run 32-bit guests.

Download Kali 32-bit from here (it is listed)

https://www.kali.org/downloads/

Comment: Thank you @Toffee but virtualisation option not found in the BIOS settings

Comment: Okay, you will have to run a 32 bit guest, get it from my answer (edited by John)